# “props” is meant to be run on 1 node. 0 found instead

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am trying to learn React thorough a udemy course. And while testing the components of my project I am facing this error which keeps popping again and again and I can't figure out what's wrong. It worked well for the instructor with exact same code.

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { DateRangePicker } from 'react-dates';
import { setTextFilter, sortByDate, sortByAmount, setStartDate, setEndDate } from '../actions/filters';

export class ExpenseListFilters extends React.Component {
 state = {
   calendarFocused: null
 };
 onDatesChange = ({ startDate, endDate }) => {
   this.props.setStartDate(startDate);
   this.props.setEndDate(endDate);
 };
 onFocusChange = (calendarFocused) => {
   this.setState(() => ({ calendarFocused }));
 }
 onTextChange = (e) => {
   this.props.setTextFilter(e.target.value);
 };
 onSortChange = (e) => {
   if (e.target.value === 'date') {
     this.props.sortByDate();
   } else if (e.target.value === 'amount') {
     this.props.sortByAmount();
   }
 };
 render() {
   return (
     <div>
       <input
         type="text"
         value={this.props.filters.text}
         onChange={this.onTextChange}
       />
       <select
         value={this.props.filters.sortBy}
         onChange={this.onSortChange}
       >
         <option value="date">Date</option>
         <option value="amount">Amount</option>
       </select>
       <DateRangePicker
       startDateId='start'
       endDateId='end'
         startDate={this.props.filters.startDate}
         endDate={this.props.filters.endDate}
         onDatesChange={this.onDatesChange}
         focusedInput={this.state.calendarFocused}
         onFocusChange={this.onFocusChange}
         showClearDates={true}
         numberOfMonths={1}
         isOutsideRange={() => false}
       />
     </div>
   );
 }
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
 filters: state.filters
});

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
 setTextFilter: (text) => dispatch(setTextFilter(text)),
 sortByDate: () => dispatch(sortByDate()),
 sortByAmount: () => dispatch(sortByAmount()),
 setStartDate: (startDate) => dispatch(setStartDate(startDate)),
 setEndDate: (endDate) => dispatch(setEndDate(endDate))
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ExpenseListFilters);
```

**And I'm trying to create a test file**

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import moment from 'moment';
import { ExpenseListFilters } from '../../components/ExpenseListFilters';
import { filters, altFilters } from '../fixtures/filters';

let setTextFilter, sortByDate, sortByAmount, setStartDate, setEndDate, wrapper;

beforeEach(() => {
  setTextFilter = jest.fn();
  sortByDate = jest.fn();
  sortByAmount = jest.fn();
  setStartDate = jest.fn();
  setEndDate = jest.fn();
  wrapper = shallow(
    <ExpenseListFilters
      filters={filters}
      setTextFilter={setTextFilter}
      sortByDate={sortByDate}
      sortByAmount={sortByAmount}
      setStartDate={setStartDate}
      setEndDate={setEndDate}
    />
  );
});

test('should render ExpenseListFilters correctly', () => {
  expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();
});

test('should render ExpenseListFilters with alt data correctly', () => {
  wrapper.setProps({
    filters: altFilters
  });
  expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();
});

test('should handle text change', () => {
  const value = 'rent';
  wrapper.find('input').simulate('change', {
    target: { value }
  });
  expect(setTextFilter).toHaveBeenLastCalledWith(value);
});

test('should sort by date', () => {
  const value = 'date';
  wrapper.setProps({
    filters: altFilters
  });
  wrapper.find('select').simulate('change', {
    target: { value }
  });
  expect(sortByDate).toHaveBeenCalled();
});

test('should sort by amount', () => {
  const value = 'amount';
  wrapper.find('select').simulate('change', {
    target: { value }
  });
  expect(sortByAmount).toHaveBeenCalled();
});

test('should handle date changes', () => {
  const startDate = moment(0).add(4, 'years');
  const endDate = moment(0).add(8, 'years');
  wrapper.find('DateRangePicker').prop('onDatesChange')({ startDate, endDate });
  expect(setStartDate).toHaveBeenLastCalledWith(startDate);
  expect(setEndDate).toHaveBeenLastCalledWith(endDate);
});

test('should handle date focus changes', () => {
  const calendarFocused = 'endDate';
  wrapper.find('DateRangePicker').prop('onFocusChange')(calendarFocused);
  expect(wrapper.state('calendarFocused')).toBe(calendarFocused);
});
```

this given error : Method “props” is meant to be run on 1 node. 0 found instead.

**I am new to React and this error keeps popping up. I've tried searching for solutions but couldn't find one. Any help would be appreciated. **

Comment: Does the error have any more context? Line number or anything like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try these two steps:

1. Import DateRangePicker in the test file.
2. Remove quotes from `wrapper.find('DateRangePicker')`, `wrapper.find(DateRangePicker)`